# How to change the maptype on the uibarbuttonitem click in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I have a tab bar that has been developed programmatically. On that tab bar I am allocating a tab bar item to which I am passing a selector. I want on that selector action that my map should switch between standard and hybrid map types.

I have added this code to my action

```
-(void)switch
{
  newmap.mygreatmapview.maptype = MKMapTypeHybrid;
}
```

`newmap` is the object of class in which mapview is present. `mygreatmapview` is property of `MKMapView` which is declared in that class.

But this not producing the result.